# which one to use `microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iis` vs `microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration`

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

What is the difference between below two nuget packages?

- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS/)
  "Provides support for hosting ASP.NET Core in IIS using the AspNetCoreModule."
- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration/)
  "ASP.NET Core components for working with the IIS AspNetCoreModule."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Server.IISIntegration` is basically the package that is responsible of integrating an ASP.NET Core application, hosted through Kestrel, into IIS with a reverse proxy setup.

`Server.IIS` is the [`IServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.iserver?view=aspnetcore-3.1) implementation that basically allows ASP.NET Core to be hosted directly *with* IIS.

So `Server.IIS` is the in-process hosting model while `Server.IISIntegration` would be the out-of-process hosting model. Although I am personally not sure if that’s exactly the separation between them; I think IISIntegration is used in both situations.

In the end though, as you can see on NuGet, both of these packages are no longer updated there. With ASP.NET Core 3.0, the packages are distributed through the shared framework as part of the .NET Core runtime. And with that, you don’t actually need to reference these packages individually any more.

If you are still on ASP.NET Core 2.1, then there is no support for the in-process hosting model, so you will need the `Server.IISIntegration` package.